# Old и new values в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Начал изучать MS SQL Server и столкнулся с такой проблемой как не знаю как обратиться к старым и новым значениям в триггере. В PL/SQL есть :old. и :new., есть ли в MS SQL подобный синтаксис или другой способ получить старые или новые значения в триггере?

Comment: DELETED/INSERTED. [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15), [OUTPUT clause](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения "старых" данных, есть специальная таблица deleted.

```
SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE id=1;
```

Для получения обновлённых данных, есть специальная таблица inserted.

```
SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE id=1;
```

Более подробно в документации: [Использование таблиц inserted и deleted](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)